# Specify Default Start Value for Autoiuncrement Column on a non primary key column?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, default-value

I have a MySQL database table that has many columns. The primary key is PKEY and one of the non primary key column is USERID. This column is set to be autoincrement & it is not a primary key. I would also like to set a default start value of 1000 so that with row insertions it would start incrementing as 1000, 1001, 1002 etc... How can I accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can only be one Auto increment column, but it can be any.  I'm assuming it's currently your PKEY field, so removing it will mean you need to manually create a unique PKEY to keep it as your primary key.

```
alter table tablename modify PKEY int(11) unsigned NOT NULL;
alter table  tablename add index (USERID);
alter table  tablename modify USERID int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;
```

a fresh create would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `foo` (
  `PKEY` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `USERID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 PRIMARY KEY (`PKEY`),
 KEY `USERID` (`USERID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;
```

However, I'd recommend you make USERID a primary key

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, but making USERID as primary key wont work. I 'NEED' to have a dedicated PKEY column for every table I create. USERID cannot take the role of PKEY. If the table can only have one auto increment column as you say then I need to make some other solution for USERID like for example USERID = PKEY + 1000 or something of that sort.

Comment: @AnupSaumithri I see, you want multiple 'autoincrementing' fields.

Comment: You could add a trigger to the table, where you don't set the USERID on insert, but update the field to be what you said PKEY + 1000

Comment: Now I like that idea. May be I can make a stored procedure for the insert and after successful row insertion and the trigger you mentioned Id like to return the UserId back to hibernate. I like your idea because logic is done inside database. I dont want hibernate to do this logic, I fear it just wont scale well and especially breakdown when it interfaces with a cluster.

Comment: @AnupSaumithri  you could manually update it by locking table, getting current max Userid and then inserting, but it will hurt performance.